# How to change the tmp directory location in ember apps

Tags: ember.js, temporary-directory

Is there a way to change the location of the `tmp` directory `ember-cli` is using to process trees? (without using symlinks)

I am trying to develop an ember app using a linux VM on a windows host. Shared folders of any type (be it virtualbox shared folders, nfs or smb) are slow, don't allow symlinks and ember-cli produces a lot of files in the tmp directory. Being able to move this `tmp` to the native filesystem of the VM would help a lot.

This should be easily configurable, but i couldn't find any configuration option that would allow it.

Answer (score 0):

No. Nobody answered and the help of the `ember-cli` build doesn't show that parameter.

Comment: I have since found a way around this by giving up on shared folders and using windows shares (samba) instead. If mounted properly in the guest (using the mfsymlinks option).

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a RAMDisk and hardlinking your project tmp folder to it? In Windows this can be done as follows:

- Create RAM DISK with `imdisk`
- `mklink /j "C:\project\tmp\" "H:\ember-tmp"` where `C:\project` is your local project folder and H: is your RAM Disk.

I'm afraid I don't know the Linux equivalents but it should be easy enough to find. Apparently this can roughly halve your build times with no chance of losing data.

Information sourced from https://emberjs-developer.quora.com/How-to-make-Ember-js-CLI-ember-s-32-times-faster and kudos to Stefan Penner for the suggestion.

Note the link folder MUST already exist before you run `mklink` otherwise you get the misleading message "Local volumes are required to complete the operation" and the link destination (junction folder) MUST NOT exist otherwise you get the message "Cannot create a file when that file already exists".

Answer (score 0):

Note as of Ember 3.0 you can now change the cache by doing the below

```
BROCCOLI_PERSISTENT_FILTER_CACHE_ROOT=/path/to/my/other/tmp/
```

This will output the broccolli files to the path of your choosing. You will need to do the tidy up operation yourself on this custom path

More information here
https://github.com/stefanpenner/async-disk-cache/issues/35